# How to write a condition for 'stdout' results?

Tags: ansible

I am writing a playbook to check if [Cisco Discovery Protocol (CDP)](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/s/article/cisco-discovery-protocol-cdp-x) is enabled on all the devices. CDP is not stored in running config so I have to use the [`ios_command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/ios/ios_command_module.html) module.

```yaml
- name: Check if CDP is running
  cisco.ios.ios_command:
    commands:
      - "show cdp | i enabled"
  register: cdp_check
  check_mode: no

- name: Check if CDP is enabled
  set_fact:
    cdp_check_status: "{{ cdp_check.stdout }}"

- name: Print Value 
  debug:
    msg: Works
  when: '"enabled" in cdp_check_status'
```

```yaml
TASK [Check if CDP is enabled] ************************************
redirecting (type: connection) ansible.builtin.network_cli to ansible.netcommon.network_cli
redirecting (type: terminal) ansible.builtin.ios to cisco.ios.ios
redirecting (type: cliconf) ansible.builtin.ios to cisco.ios.ios
redirecting (type: become) ansible.builtin.enable to ansible.netcommon.enable 
ok: [atl01-sw-lab01] => {
  "ansible_facts": {         
     "cdp_check_status": [
         "Sending CDPv2 advertisements is  enabled"
     ]
  },
  "changed": false
}
TASK [Print Value] ************************************
skipping: [atl01-sw-lab01] => {}
```

My test failed and therefore the task becomes skipped.

Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Here's the play output
TASK [Check if CDP is enabled] 
ok: [atl01-sw-lab01] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "cdp_check_status": [
            "Sending CDPv2 advertisements is  enabled"
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [Print Value] skipping: [atl01-sw-lab01] => {}

Comment: Please [edit] and add a clear debug output of `cdp_check`.

Answer (score 0):

In the given example the result

```json
ansible_facts": {         
     "cdp_check_status": [
         "Sending CDPv2 advertisements is  enabled"
     ]
  }
```

is a list with one element. Therefore the content of `cdp_check` [`.stdout`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/ios/ios_command_module.html#return-values) too.

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    cdp_check:
      stdout:
        - "Sending CDPv2 advertisements is  enabled"

  tasks:

  - name: Print Value
    debug:
      msg: "Works"
    when: cdp_check.stdout is search('enabled')
```

will result in to the requested output of

```yaml
TASK [Print Value] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: Works
```

**Further Documentation**

- [Testing strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings)

Comment: Your solution worked.
Thank you !!!